# trying to view the pdf document using ionic document-viewer not working

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, documentviewer

I want to view a pdf document using ionic document viewer. it is not working in app.Pls help.

<a (click)="onlinePDF(row)"> View PDF

import { DocumentViewer, DocumentViewerOptions } from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/document-viewer/ngx';

async onlinePDF(row : any){
const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
title: 'View PDF'
}
this.document.viewDocument('https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf', 'application/pdf', options);
}

when we click the link nothing happening.

i have the small sample project whatever i tried. if you want will share.

Comment: You need to download the file from the url first and then open the local file with document viewer. You can also look into ngx-extended-pdf-viewer that allow you to pass a blob as the source (it avoids a conversion so still nice).